# Preg_match_all для нескольких паттернов

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

На сайте я реализовал подключение плагинов с помощью регулярки с функцией обратного вызова. Так,  фраза в  контенте `{{my_plugin}}` заменяется на соответствующий  php-код с инициализацией переменной $_html, содержащий html-разметку.

Появилась необходимость создать еще один тип вставки - вставка javascript-кода - и будет он выглядеть как `[[javascript:src]]`

Придется ли мне делать дополнительный поиск по регулярному выражению, или в одном поиске можно объединить два паттерна?

**Код интеграции паттерна:**

```
$this->data['content'] =  preg_replace_callback("/{{(.*)}}/",function($matches){
  $plugin = $matches[1];
  if (file_exists("plugins/$plugin.php")) require_once  "plugins/$plugin.php";
   else $_html = "";
 return $_html;
}, $this->data['content']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам придется создать дополнытельный поиск, так как у вас скобки разные `{{my_plugin}}` с `{{}}` а `[[javascript:src]]` с `[[]]`

либо сделайте оба `{{}}`

и этот же Ваш код будет работать

Comment: Спасибо! Я уже давно сделал одинаковые скобки {{}},  а уже далее php парсит строку в скобках и "принимает решение" по поводу подключения того или иного скрипа (если указано "двоеточие", то подключаются java-скрипты).